# Advanced Search Options: "intags: mine" does not support [tag:wildcards*]

Tags: bug, search, tag-search

I sometimes use the [advanced search options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to look for questions to answer.

For example I may search for questions with: [answers:0 score:1 created:2018-02 intags:mine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20answers%3A0%20score%3A1%20created%3A2018-02%20intags%3Amine)

I've recently started using wild card tags: [[sql-server*]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server*) in my favourites instead of lots of tags with different versions of [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), like so:

---

[image]

---

However, it seems that **intags: mine** does not support the wildcard as I get 0 results for [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) when I use the wildcard in my favourites.